# pgfplotstable, externalize and list-and-make with auxiliary output directory

Tags: latexmk, auxiliary-files, externalize

I am setting up a `.latexmkrc` configuration for my workflow with `latexmk`, and ran into a dead end regarding a pathing/lookup problem.

### my setup so far (use as MWE)

#### `.latexmkrc`:

```bash
# Set the program used to generate the PDF
# 1: pdflatex
# 2: postscript conversion, don't use this
# 3: dvi conversion, don't use this
# 4: lualatex
# 5: xelatex
$pdf_mode = 1;

# Move all axuiliary files to a separate directory, so they do not clutter up the project directory
$emulate_aux = 1;
$aux_dir = "tmp";

# Move the compiled files (and synctex) to a separate directory
$out_dir = 'build';

set_tex_cmds(" --shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode  -file-line-error -synctex=1 ");


$clean_ext .= ' %R.figlist %R-figure* %R.makefile fls.tmp';

$latex    = 'internal tikzlatex latex    %B %O %S';
$pdflatex = 'internal tikzlatex pdflatex %B %O %S';
$lualatex = 'internal tikzlatex lualatex %B %O %S';
$xelatex  = 'internal tikzlatex xelatex  %B %O %S';

$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^(/CreationDate|/ModDate|/ID)';
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'ps'} = '^%%CreationDate';

sub tikzlatex {
    my ($engine, $base, @args) = @_;
    my $ret = 0;
    print "Tikzlatex: ===Running '$engine @args'...\n";
    $ret = system( $engine, @args );
    print "Tikzlatex: Fixing .fls file ...\n";
    system "echo INPUT \"$aux_dir1$base.figlist\"  >  \"$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp\"";
    system "echo INPUT \"$aux_dir1$base.makefile\" >> \"$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp\"";
    system "cat \"$aux_dir1$base.fls\"    >> \"$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp\"";
    rename "$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp", "$aux_dir1$base.fls";
    if ($ret) { return $ret; }



    if ( -e "$aux_dir1$base.makefile" ) {
        system "echo \"$aux_dir1$base.makefile\"";

        if ($engine eq 'xelatex') {
                print "Tikzlatex: ---Correcting '$aux_dir1$base.makefile' made under xelatex\n";
            system( 'perl', '-i', '-p', '-e', 's/^\^\^I/\t/', "$aux_dir1$base.makefile" );
        }
        elsif ($engine eq 'latex') {
            print "Tikzlatex: ---Correcting '$aux_dir1$base.makefile' made under latex\n";
            system( 'perl', '-i', '-p', '-e', 's/\.epsi/\.ps/', "$aux_dir1$base.makefile" );
        }

        print "Tikzlatex: ---Running 'make -f $aux_dir1$base.makefile' ...\n";

        if ($aux_dir) {
            # latexmk has set $ENV{TEXINPUTS} in this case.
            my $SAVETEXINPUTS = $ENV{TEXINPUTS};
            $ENV{TEXINPUTS} = good_cwd().$search_path_separator.$ENV{TEXINPUTS};
                pushd( $aux_dir );
                $ret = system "make",  "-j", "5", "-f", "$base.makefile";
                &popd;
                $ENV{TEXINPUTS} = $SAVETEXINPUTS;
            }
            else {
                $ret = system "make",  "-j", "5", "-f", "$base.makefile";
            }

        if ($ret) {
            print "Tikzlatex: !!!!!!!!!!!!!! Error from make !!!!!!!!! \n",
                "  The log files for making the figures '$aux_dir1$base-figure*.log'\n",
                "  may have information\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        print "Tikzlatex: No '$aux_dir1$base.makefile', so I won't run make.\n";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

#### `mwe.tex`: (not working)

```latex
% mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{external}

% NOTE: data.csv cannot be generated fromfilecontents, as it end up in /tmp then

\tikzexternalize[
    mode=list and make,
    only named=true,%
] % activate

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{external-figure}%
    % \tikzpicturedependsonfile{src/data.csv}
    \input{src/figure.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### `src/data.csv`:

```
 x, y
 0, 0
 1, 1
```

#### `src/figure.tikz`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread[
        col sep = comma,
    ]{src/data.csv}{\dataX}

    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table from {\dataX};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

### Problem description:

During compilation, `make -f tmp/mwe.makefile` cannot find the file `tmp/data.csv`, but it has to be given relative to the root file for regular input.

I want to be able to keep using the aux-dir setup, in order to separate the multitude of temporary files my documents create from the source files and from the output files.

I do not believe this is an issue with `pgfplotstable`, but with the search paths in general, when using auxiliary directories. `pgfplotstable` is to be understood as example then.

### Investigated solutions:

1. If I move `\pgfplotstableread` into `mwe.tex`, instead of it being part of the input, `latexmk` runs through without errors. *I would prefer bundling the loading of data inside the tikzpicture environments, as in my MW(n)E.**
2. The obvious next step: Moving `\pgfplotstableread` outside the `tikzpicture` environment, but keeping it inside `src/figure.tikz` would be an acceptable solution, but throws the error as well.

### Seeking advice

I am lost and have run out of ideas what to try next. Can anyone give advice on:

- how to achieve the desired behaviour?
- how to automatically modify the makefile that `externalize` and `list-and-make` create accordingly?

Comment: I get a slightly different error.  With exactly your `.latexmkrc` and other files, there is a cd to the aux directory before make is invoked.  The error is then that `src/data.csv` is not found.  I solved this by putting a symlink in the aux dir to the `src` directory.   This is a fudge but works.

Comment: Thank you @john-collins. Your suggestion pointed me into the right direction. I have elaborated my solution in its own answer.

Comment: @JohnCollins You seem to be an avid defender and user of ``latexmrc`` (beside being the author) and using build and aux directories to split output and auxiliary files. Do you mind sharing a copy of your latexmrc config, because mine seems to have more problems than I anticipated (especially with gnuplot and externalize in view of references, but this is not deterministically reproducable, so I can't make a question out of it.).

Answer (score 0):

I have taken up the comment by John Collins and refined my `.latexmkrc` accordingly. To try it out, run it together with the other files initially provided in my M(n)WE.

### `.latexmkrc`:

```perl
# Set the program used to generate the PDF
# 1: pdflatex
# 2: postscript conversion, don't use this
# 3: dvi conversion, don't use this
# 4: lualatex
# 5: xelatex
$pdf_mode = 1;

# Move all axuiliary files to a separate directory, so they do not clutter up the project directory
$emulate_aux = 1;
$aux_dir = "tmp";

# Move the compiled files (and synctex) to a separate directory
$out_dir = 'build';

# This is the directory latexmk links for makefiles inside the $aux_dir: Place all external resources here.
$source_dir = "src";

# Produce less console output
$silent = 1;

set_tex_cmds(" --shell-escape  -interaction=nonstopmode  -file-line-error -synctex=1 ");


$clean_ext .= ' %R.figlist %R-figure* %R.makefile fls.tmp';

$latex    = 'internal tikzlatex latex    %B %O %S';
$pdflatex = 'internal tikzlatex pdflatex %B %O %S';
$lualatex = 'internal tikzlatex lualatex %B %O %S';
$xelatex  = 'internal tikzlatex xelatex  %B %O %S';

$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^(/CreationDate|/ModDate|/ID)';
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'ps'} = '^%%CreationDate';

sub tikzlatex {
    my ($engine, $base, @args) = @_;
    my $ret = 0;
    print "Tikzlatex: ===Running '$engine @args'...\n";
    $ret = system( $engine, @args );
    print "Tikzlatex: Fixing .fls file ...\n";
    system "echo INPUT \"$aux_dir1$base.figlist\"  >  \"$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp\"";
    system "echo INPUT \"$aux_dir1$base.makefile\" >> \"$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp\"";
    system "cat \"$aux_dir1$base.fls\"    >> \"$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp\"";
    rename "$aux_dir1$base.fls.tmp", "$aux_dir1$base.fls";
    if ($ret) { return $ret; }




    if ( -e "$aux_dir1$base.makefile" ) {
        system "echo \"$aux_dir1$base.makefile\"";

        if ($engine eq 'xelatex') {
                print "Tikzlatex: ---Correcting '$aux_dir1$base.makefile' made under xelatex\n";
            system( 'perl', '-i', '-p', '-e', 's/^\^\^I/\t/', "$aux_dir1$base.makefile" );
        }
        elsif ($engine eq 'latex') {
            print "Tikzlatex: ---Correcting '$aux_dir1$base.makefile' made under latex\n";
            system( 'perl', '-i', '-p', '-e', 's/\.epsi/\.ps/', "$aux_dir1$base.makefile" );
        }

        print "Tikzlatex: ---Running 'make -f $aux_dir1$base.makefile' ...\n";

        if ($aux_dir) {
            # latexmk has set $ENV{TEXINPUTS} in this case.
            my $SAVETEXINPUTS = $ENV{TEXINPUTS};
            $ENV{TEXINPUTS} = good_cwd().$search_path_separator.$ENV{TEXINPUTS};

            # since some files are trying to get source files during compilation of the externalize list-and-make makefile, provide them with a symlink to the source files:
            $current_dir = getcwd();
            $existing_file = "$current_dir/$source_dir";
            $new_file = "$current_dir/$aux_dir/$source_dir";



            my $symlink_exists = eval { symlink (  $existing_file, $new_file);; 1 };

            if (not($symlink_exists)) {
                print "Tikzlatex: ---Creation of symlink failed. Please create a symlink from '$aux_dir/$source_dir' to '<document root>/$source_dir' manually.\n";

            }

            pushd( $aux_dir );
            $ret = system "make",  "-j", "5", "-f", "$base.makefile";
            &popd;
            $ENV{TEXINPUTS} = $SAVETEXINPUTS;
            }
            else {
                $ret = system "make",  "-j", "5", "-f", "$base.makefile";
            }

        if ($ret) {
            print "Tikzlatex: !!!!!!!!!!!!!! Error from make !!!!!!!!! \n",
                "  The log files for making the figures '$aux_dir1$base-figure*.log'\n",
                "  may have information\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        print "Tikzlatex: No '$aux_dir1$base.makefile', so I won't run make.\n";
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

In particular, I want to point out the following added lines:

```perl
# This is the directory latexmk links for makefiles inside the $aux_dir: Place all external resources here.
$source_dir = "src";
```

```perl
# since some files are trying to get source files during compilation of the externalize list-and-make makefile, provide them with a symlink to the source files:
$current_dir = getcwd();
$existing_file = "$current_dir/$source_dir";
$new_file = "$current_dir/$aux_dir/$source_dir";

my $symlink_exists = eval { symlink (  $existing_file, $new_file);; 1 };

if (not($symlink_exists)) {
    print "Tikzlatex: ---Creation of symlink failed. Please create a symlink from '$aux_dir/$source_dir' to '<document root>/$source_dir' manually.\n";

}
```

which automatically generate the symlink (on most platforms) needed to find the external dependencies.

Manual creation of the symlink was not an option, as I fear other users will delete the `$aux_dir`, and not know or not remember to reinstall the symlink.

If anyone wants to add their suggestions, I am happy to improve my script.